# Mixed JS and HTML not working. Assistance?

Tags: javascript, html

Code below.

I'm complete balls at JS, and I have no idea what I did wrong. I /had/ it working, so that when the user input a name, it would display `'Name: {outputn}'` on the next page after clicking submit. Afterwards, I put in a form html field below it, not displayed here because it was removed, and now it no longer works, even though it's the same code I had previously.

PS: In addition, if someone happens to know, is there a way I could add additional fields, ex gender, and have them be applied with the same submit button?

```
<div class="content active">Username: <input type="text" id="userName"></input>
<script>
    var didClickIt = false;
    document.getElementById("submitter").addEventListener("click",function(){
        didClickIt = true;
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        if( didClickIt ) {
            didClickIt = false;
            var o=document.getElementById("outputn"),v=document.getElementById("userName").value;
            if(o.textContent!==undefined){
                o.textContent=v;
            }else{
                o.innerText=v;
            }
        }
    },05);
</script>
<button id="submitter" style="background:#ffffff;">Submit</button><br>
</div>
<div class="content"><p>Name: <div id="outputn"></div></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work for me here http://jsfiddle.net/NA9BM/2/

I added another element so you can see how you could do it with the same logic.

```
<div class="content active">
  Username: <input type="text" id="userName"></input><br>
  Email: <input type="text" id="email"></input>
  <button id="submitter" style="background:#ffffff;">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Name: 
    <div id="outputn"></div>
  </p>
  <p>Email:
    <div id="outpute"></div>
  </p>
</div>
```

And the js

```
var didClickIt = false;
document.getElementById("submitter").addEventListener("click",function(){
  didClickIt = true;
});

setInterval(function(){
  if( didClickIt ) {
    didClickIt = false;
    var o=document.getElementById("outputn"), v=document.getElementById("userName").value;
    var eo = document.getElementById("outpute"), e = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if(o.textContent!==undefined && eo.textContent!==undefined){
      o.textContent=v;
      eo.textContent=e;
    }else{
      o.innerText=v;
      eo.innerText=e;
    }
  }
},05);
```

You can try putting the script tag on the bottom to let the DOM load correctly before actually loading the script.

Answer (score 0):

Place your `<script>` block after you have already declared your `#submitter` element - `addEventListener()` can't listen to events on nodes that haven't already appeared in the page.

Additionally, your code is **overly complicated**. Instead of checking to see if the button has been checked, just have the event fire your code directly when the listener is triggered:

```
document.getElementById("submitter").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var o = document.getElementById("outputn"),
        v = document.getElementById("userName").value;
    if (o.textContent !== undefined) {
        o.textContent = v;
    } else {
        o.innerText = v;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code in the `<script>` block is executed *as the page loads*, so it will encounter and execute `getElementById("submitter")` before the `<button id="submitter">` is encountered by the browser.

Move your code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event-handler, then the `submitter` element will be available:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
     var didClickIt = false;
     document.getElementById("submitter").addEventListener("click",function(){
        didClickIt = true;
     });
});
```

Another option is to move the `<script>` block to the bottom of the page.

If you need to support older browsers, use `window.onload` instead of `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 0):

Move your script part at the end of document.
When executing the line:

```
document.getElementById("submitter")
```

DOM was not ready (not all elements created) so your search for "submitter" produced NULL.

In fact, the proper way is to wait DOM to create all elements - see documentation for JavaScript or use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
    //Your code
}
window.onload = init;
</script>
```